# Identificador automatico Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebars

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
{{#each horarios}}
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2"> <label for="cbox2">{{ horario }} </label>                     
{{/each}}
```

Y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma que `Handlebars` ponga el id automáticamente y que sea único para  cada `checkbox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `{{@index}}` para obtener el índice actual del array sobre el que estás iterando:

```
{{#each horarios}}
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox{{@index}}"> <label for="cbox{{@index}}"> {{ horario }} </label>                     
{{/each}}
```

Comment: @Pablo Lozano Bien visto  ;-)